# SiUSBxp.dll + JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am  trying to use siUSBxp.dll with java using(JNA) generally every thing fine

but I have problem with SI_CheckRXQueue sometimes it is working fine but sometimes give

"QueueStatus = SI_RX_NO_OVERRUN)" this problem happens only in java

I tried to use same function in c++ it is always working correctly but in java most of the times give me "Queue-status = SI_RX_NO_OVERRUN" and NumBytesInQueue, =0 
This is java implementation using JNA  :

```
    int SI_CheckRXQueue (HANDLE Handle, IntByReference NumBytesInQueue,IntByReference QueueStatus);
```

This is native C siUSBxp.dll code

```
   SI_STATUS SI_CheckRXQueue (HANDLE Handle, LPDWORD NumBytesInQueue,LPDWORD QueueStatus)
```

could you please help me to

Comment: What does your documentation tell you that that status means?

Comment: i use this programmer Giude:  https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an169.pdf

Comment: `SI_RX_NO_OVERRUN` is aliased to `SI_RX_EMPTY`.  Sounds like your buffer is empty.  Perhaps you missed an initialization step when translating to Java.

Comment: but java code some times working fine ,we can say like this "5 times working well and then one time stop" .... so do you think that such this problem related to code or to driver it self or other thing ..what do you think?